# How to add "and others" at the end of a \parencites citation?

Tags: biblatex, biber

I'm sorry to ask something I can't really show code for, but I've no idea where even to start. At the moment, I have a bibliography entry that looks like this:

```
@book{andothers,
  title = {and others},
  author = {and others},
}
```

So that I can do this:

```
The world is pretty cool! \parencites[3]{CurieAtoms}[1]{EinsteinRelativity}[2]{DarwinEvolution}{andothers}, especially when there's ice cream for dessert.
```

To get this:

> The world is pretty cool (Curie 1932:3, Einstein 1953:1, Darwin 1880:2, and others), especially when there's ice cream for dessert.

My question is, what would the "proper" way to achieve this be? Preferrably even without that last comma? I.e.:

> The world is pretty cool (Curie 1932:3, Einstein 1953:1, Darwin 1880:2 and others), especially when there's ice cream for dessert.

Comment: Set the option `maxcitenames=3, mincitenames=3` on loading `biblatex`. If you want these etings to be valid also in the references, just use  `maxnames=3, minnames=3`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Bernard! That's a useful thing to know, but not exactly what I meant. I would like to add "and others" unrelated to how many names were actually cited. It could be 2 or it could be 10. Is that "too manual" for BibLaTeX?

Comment: I seem to have misundertood you: what you want is to put a limit on the number of simultaneous citations, not the number of authors for a particular citation. Is that correct?

Comment: Mmm no, I don't want any such magic (no counting or limiting of anything at all). I simply want to add the string _" and others"_ at the end, right before the closing parantheses.

Comment: The various `\cites` commands take this general form: `\parencites(<multiprenote>)(<multipostnote>)[<pre>][<post>]{<entrykey-1>}...[<pre>][<post>]{<entrykey-n>}`. So: `\parencites(and others)[3]{CurieAtoms}[1]{EinsteinRelativity}[2]{DarwinEvolution}`.

Comment: @jon Oops. Just realised I answered with your comment. Though I would probably do `\autocites(and others)[3]{CurieAtoms}[1]{EinsteinRelativity}[2]{DarwinEvolution}`.

Comment: @cfr -- You are too kind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Biblatex, as usual, has you covered. The various `\(*)cites` commands take this general form:

```
\parencites(<multiprenote>)(<multipostnote>)[<pre>][<post>]{<entrykey-1>}...[<p‌​re>][<post>]{<entrykey-n>}.
```

So you can do something like:

```
\parencites(and others)[3]{CurieAtoms}[1]{EinsteinRelativity}[2]{DarwinEvolution}
```

or even:

```
\parencites(I rank discoveries by page numbers)(and others)[and third:][3]{CurieAtoms}[1]{EinsteinRelativity}[second:][2]{DarwinEvolution}
```

As cfr noted in her deleted answer, there is also the "higher-level":

```
\autocites(and others)[3]{CurieAtoms}[1]{EinsteinRelativity}[2]{DarwinEvolution}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you both so much! I continue to be amazed by Biblatex, but it's also a deep, deep ocean of things to learn :-)